# JQuery .each only returning one <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable1 venuetags" class="connectedSortable">
   <li id="venuetagli">fried</li>
   <li id="venuetagli">garlic</li>
   <li id="venuetagli">rosemary</li>
   <li id="venuetagli">new potatoes</li>
</ul>
```

And am trying to get the values of each using JQuery:

```
$('#venuetagli').each(function(j,li) {
   console.log(j,li)
})
```

However, from the console I am only getting the first value returned.

Comment: Id's should not be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ids <strike>are supposed to</strike> must be unique that is why you are getting single element use class selector instead. Also the id of `UL` would not have space.

*Html*

```
<ul id="sortable1 venuetags" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="venuetagli">fried</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">garlic</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">rosemary</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">new potatoes</li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('.venuetagli').each(function(j,li) {
   console.log(j,li)
});
```

You can simple get the li with ul using parent-child selector

```
$('#sortable1 li').each(function(j,li) {
   console.log(j,li)
});
```

Just for the test and never recommended way, you can get elements having same id using attribute selector.

```
$('[id=venuetagli]').each(function(j,li) {
   console.log(j,li);
});
```

Comment: You wont get error for multiple elements with same ids and can access them buy indirect method

Comment: We don't get error hoeever if we use them HTML becomes invalid and thus one can't predict how browsers will behave. So in short __Element IDs must be unique in entire document__

Comment: Yes, more appropriate would be "The ids must be unique"

Answer (score 1):

Id must be assign to a single element in complete page else it will return only one of those element or unexpected result:

[Here is demo with class](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/8n5j3/)

```
<ul id="sortable1 venuetags" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="venuetagli">fried</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">garlic</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">rosemary</li>
   <li class="venuetagli">new potatoes</li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('.venuetagli').each(function(j,li) {
   console.log(j,li)
})
```